# Display PHP loop results instantly on every event with or without javascript

Tags: javascript, php, loops

I have this part of PHP code:

```
for ($x=0; $x<$attempts; $x++) {
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    if ($fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)) {
        $endtime = microtime(true);
        $time = round((($endtime - $starttime) * 1000), 0)." ms";
        echo "Ping $host Succesfull in $time<br>";
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        echo "Can't Ping<br>";
    }
}
```

I would like it to display the output interactively say with one second delay in between results.

Have tried with

`flush()` and `ob_flush()` and `ob_implicit_flush(true);`

but no luck, i get the results after the script finishes completely.

Is it possible to do it with JavaScript, or PHP itself, i don't care...

Best regards

Comment: is your code working properly, I mean you have just one equal sign in your if statement ?

Comment: you mean you want to see the result in a browser ? this wont work like you tried because the response will not come before the for loop ended, you better do your ping with js, use jquery and its ajax extension, this is very easy

Comment: Have you used `ob_start()` at the beginning of your script before you call `ob_flush()`? You have to start buffering first with `ob_start()` else the buffer you push to the browser with `ob_flush()` is empty.

Comment: @Mritunjay, yes, my code works ok when i add host, port and number of attempts it works as many times as $attempts variable is set, but i want to display those results one by one with one second delay in my browser; and yes, I used ob_start() but no luck

Comment: Collect results to an array and then iterate over this result array using js. Then you can add sleep time or whatever fancy staff.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you give me an example how to do it with js with one second delay between results?

Comment: you might have a look at multipart http response (or so)

Comment: @Mritunjay Considering `$fp` isn't assigned before the `if` statement, and what it's being assigned to in the `if` statement, I'd be worried if there *weren't* just one equals sign.

Comment: Can anyone post any example on how it can be done, i still haven't solved it...